# does gensim.corpora wikiCorpus work only with bz2 file?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, wikipedia, dump

I'm trying to load a wiki dump (.gz) and use it in gensim word2vec. I convert it into bz2 using bzip2 in terminal but Wikicorpus class seems to refuse the file. Can someone please explain me how to get the text from a wiki dump in a easy way?
thanks

Comment: What does "seems to refuse the file" mean? (Was there an error message? Can you add it to your question?) Which wiki dump, from where, are you trying to read? What made you think you needed to convert the file from its original format, and what command "in terminal" did you use to do that?

Comment: I pass to wikiCorpus class a .gz wiki abstract dump and not a pages-articles bz2 from [link](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/). From documentation [link](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/wikicorpus.html#module-gensim.corpora.wikicorpus) the supported dump formats are
<LANG>wiki-<YYYYMMDD>-pages-articles.xml.bz2 & <LANG>wiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2. For this reason Gensim got a namespace error. I want to use an abstract dump .gz to create a gensim word2vec model with abstract text. I'm new in parsing xml. is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WikiCorpus` utility class in Gensim expects the `pages-articles` dumps, not different dumps containing only abstracts.

To read another format, you'll need to write your own code.

Some things you could try:

- Study the [source for the WikiCorpus class](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/corpora/wikicorpus.py) & use it as a model for your own code, adapting it to read the different elements out of your other dump.
- Use some other utility, for example the [command-line tool `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or similar, to just dump the relevant text from the XML element(s) of interest, into a plain-text file, which you could then read line-by-line in Python (to either further preprocess/tokenize or even just feed directly to Gensim's `LineSentence` helper class).